# Convert XElement to JObject without JSON -or- Configure SerializeXNode for Empty Elements

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net, xelement

I am using Json.NET's ability to [convert XML to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) and it works pretty well. I say "pretty well" because it will map empty XML nodes to `null` instead of `{}` (empty JSON object). However, because this web-services result *drives* a knockout.js binding, I need empty XML elements to map to `{}` in order to maintain the binding structure<sup>1</sup>.

The current approach looks like:

```
// Json.NET XML->JSON
// Can I specify any custom converters for this?
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);

// JSON->JObject
var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

// Update all `null` values to `{}`
// This "works reliably" because XML properties can never be null, but is
// hackish in its own right.
ConvertNullToEmptyObject(jObject as JContainer);

// And we're back at JSON, but I'd like to avoid such
// a complicated XML->JSON->JObject(Fixup)->JSON route.
// Performance isn't an issue, but it just feels dirty.
var finalJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
```

So then (the questions!);

1. How can the roundabout trip through JSON be *avoided*?
2. Is there a better way to convert an XElement to JSON (applying special rules) to begin with?

Notes:

- I am aware I could write my *own* `XElement->JObject` conversion function (using the same rules, or even code, as Json.NET), but I would like to re-use library support if possible. If you think I should just do this to start with, leave a comment saying so.
- I would like to stick to Json.NET, but would not be dissuaded from looking at alternative or supplemental libraries as long as they are free, small, and work in .NET 3.5.

---

<sup>1</sup> The general approach of `knockout<-JSON<-WS(XML)->JSON->knockout` works quite well. This issue here is that standard knockout.js template bindings (in conjunction with `ko.mapping`) will *not* "auto-vivify" the structure even though binding to nonexistent properties (within an existing structure) works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a better answer, write it. Accepted answers can be changed.

---

Well, I'm going to say this is "not reasonably possible" with Json.NET.

I cracked open [Json.NET's XmlNodeConverter](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69709#128123) and it only interfaces externally with JsonReader and JsonWriter.

While it *would* likely be possible to write a JObjectReader and a JObjectWriter, this would involve more work than I am currently willing to invest.

Alternatively, I could copy *all* of the XmlNodeConverter code (most of it is private/internal) and modify it per my requirements - but this sort of copy'n'paste mass-duplication rubs me wrong.

What I have now works well enough, even if does seem wasteful.